# How does friction affect simple harmonic motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, friction, harmonic-oscillator, spring

Today I had my Physics final exam. In it, we were asked to find the time at which a block attached to a spring on a horizontal surface came to a halt knowing that there is friction. Also, we had the initial conditions (equilibrium position at *t = 0* and its corresponding initial velocity).

I have never solved a problem like this with friction. I just ignored it since when doing the analysis of forces that act on the object, it is just a term that does not depend on *x*. Is this okay or should we take friction into account?

I am posting this here to gain some insight in this topic, this is *not* a homework question since I already finished this course. I just want to understand SHM.

All help appreciated.

**Edit**: the exact statement (as I remember) is:

> A block is against a spring at rest at x = 0. Knowing that it is given
>   a slight push so that its initial speed is 2 m/s, calculate the
>   position at which the block comes to rest for the second time.
>
> Data: mass = 1 kg; $\mu_k = 0.3$; k = 900 N/m

Comment: Look up things on [damped simple harmonic oscillators](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DampedSimpleHarmonicMotion.html).

Comment: Hi Bee. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: Could you give us some more details on the exact problem that you had to solve? It would help us come up with an answer better suited to your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use energy conservation.

The block has initial kinetic energy $K_0=\frac 12 mv_0^2$.

- Until the first stop this is turned into elastic potential energy $U_1=\frac 12 kx_1^2$ and energy loss by friction: $W_{0-1}=f_k(x_1-x_0)=\mu_k n x_1$.
- The energy stored at the first stop is until the second stop again turned into elastic potential energy $U_2=\frac 12 kx_2^2$ and friction loss: $W_{1-2}=\mu_k n (x_2-x_1)$.

Set up the two equations, and it looks like you only have the two positions as unknowns. This should be simple algebra to solve if I didn't miss something.

Comment: Thank you. How could we get the time at which this happens? @Steeven

Comment: @Bee The time? That is a bit more tricky. You must look into the motion equation of the object. The two other answers include that.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
It turns out that this answer is rather irrelevant as it does not address the question at hand which was edited to show that it speaks of *kinetic* friction as opposed to viscous damping as assumed here.

---

Let's try and understand what's happening physically, so that when we get our mathematical answer, we can check to see if it makes sense. Something I like to do first is consider *limiting* cases. Let's assume your block's on a table that is completely frictionless. In this ideal case, it would continue to oscillate with a constant amplitude.

Now consider a small frictional force. Since I don't know what model of friction they asked you to solve for, the standard model for such problems introduces a "damping" term that is proportional to the *velocity* of the particle at that time, so while it does not depend explicitly on the position, it is certainly not a constant! Well, with a small frictional force, the object would continue to oscillate, but it wouldn't be unreasonable to assume that the amplitude would start to decrease ever so slightly with each oscillation.

Now what if I introduced a *large* damping force? Imagine stretching out your block-on-a-spring and letting it go. The damping would be so strong that the object would not oscillate at all, but just come to rest. Thus our solution must clearly have two regimes, separated by some characteristic value of one of the parameters (say, $\gamma$, the damping coefficient).

Let's actually try and compute something with this. When you describe the forces acting on the particle,  you must now include a *frictional force*, given by $F_v = \gamma mv = -\gamma m\dot{x}$, where the dots refer to differentiation with respect to time. Note that $\gamma$ must be positive, since the frictional force is always in the opposite direction of the velocity, as it works to slow down the particle! How does Newton's equation $F=ma$ look now?

$$F = m \ddot{x}=-k x - \gamma m \dot{x}$$

Writing this out explicitly, you see that

$$\ddot{x} + \gamma \dot{x} + \omega^2 x = 0$$

Such a differential equation is slightly harder to solve that the simple case, but the same rather standard technique can be used: consider a solution of the form $x(t) = A e^{\alpha t}$. The exponential has the nice property that is converts such differential equations into algebraic equations. Plugging it into the equation, you'd get that

$$\alpha^2 + \gamma \alpha + \omega^2 = 0$$

which would lead you to two distinct values of $\alpha$ (as we would expect, since it's a *second* order differential equation with two solutions in general), $\alpha_+$ and $\alpha_-$.

$$\alpha_{\pm} = \frac{-\gamma}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{\gamma^2}{4} - \omega^2}$$

We now see something interesting: remember (for real $a$) that when you have a function $e^{-a t}$, it is an exponentially decaying solution, while a function $e^{iat}$ is an *oscillatory* solution (it can be expressed as a linear sum of sines and cosines).

Let's observe one of our solutions, say

$$e^{\alpha_1 t} = e^{-\frac{\gamma}{2}t}\,e^{t\sqrt{\frac{\gamma^2}{4} - \omega^2}}$$

We can now see that for all values of $\gamma^2\geq 4\omega^2$, the solution is purely an exponential decay. However, when $\gamma^2< 4\omega^2$, a critical value we intuitively imagined would exist, the solution is a combination of an exponentially decaying part and an oscillating part, since the root is imaginary!

I agree with @James' comment that finding the solution for it to come to rest might be relatively difficult if you haven't been exposed to this before, but nevertheless we can still get some information out of this solution. As can be seen, when $\gamma^2< 4\omega^2$, the final solution of a damped harmonic oscillation is just something of the form:

$$x(t) = e^{-\frac{\gamma}{2}t} \left(A \sin \omega_1 t + B\cos \omega_1 t \right)$$

where $\omega_1$ is just some constant modified frequency, different from the natural frequency of the system. We can clearly see that there is a *time scale* associated to this problem (this is an argument that is made very often in physics), related to the inverse of $\gamma$. The exponential function is very rapidly decreasing, at $e^{-2}\approx 0.1$, the amplitude has already decreased by a factor of 10. I might be able to answer more if you actually gave us the exact question, but I hope this helped!

Comment: Just curious, why do you assume that it's a _viscous_ damping term?  There is friction; but it doesn't suggest that it's a viscous friction.  The way I interpret this question it has a kinetic friction term, not a viscous damping term.  It seems the question was edited to show that it _isn't_ a viscous damping term.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have not seen differential equations in class yet, and we had a very brief introduction to oscillations, so I am not able to perfectly understand this damped motion, but I find the topic really interesting and would like to know more about it. Your answer has given me some insight onto it. One question is: how would we express this in terms of energy? Would it be different from that of SHM? Also, I just edited the initial post so that the statement is included.

Comment: @Bee Be careful with these answers.  They are showing **viscous** damping.  In viscous damping, the "frictional" force is directly proportional to velocity.  In your edits, it's clear that this is not the case, instead the friction force will not vary with the velocity, so these solutions aren't representative of your question (though with the missing details I can understand where the assumption came from).

Comment: Okay, thank you. I apologise as I realise I should have included more details from the beginning. I do appreciate reading more about oscillations though. @JMac

Comment: @Bee If you plan on studying physics further you will begin to encounter these differential equations.  It's definitely not bad to be exposed to them early; just a little misleading in this case.  Definitely worth reading into though.  It can (roughly) apply to a lot of physical systems.

Comment: Aah! Notice that the question makes everything clearer! They ask you to find  "the position at which the block comes to rest for the *second* time".

It is not asking for the position where the block stops forever (this was my understanding of "came to a halt", sorry!) What they're asking you to do is find out the position where it *velocity* is zero. 

You're right, @JMac, the question doesn't really seem to be about viscous damping at all, my answer isn't relevant, sorry about that!

Comment: @PhilipCherian "Coming to rest" completely actually makes more sense for his example compared to a damped harmonic oscillator anyways.  Damped oscillation never stops (mathematically),  the amplitude just gets increasingly close to 0.  The best you could do is solve for a time when it has some % of it's initial velocity, since you'll never reach 0.

Comment: Thank you to all of you. Finally, in this type of motion where there is friction but it is a constant force, would we still be considering the same type of SHM?

Comment: Essentially, in that case the problem would be exactly the same as the harmonic oscillator without friction, except that the oscillations will no longer be around $0$, but around some new equilibrium point, which should be something like $$x_0 = \frac{F_c}{m\omega^2}$$

I'm trying to think of a simple way to see this without using differential equations. In the meantime, @Steeven's answer looks promising.

Comment: @PhilipCherian I initially thought that, but that's also not how it would work.  It's not the same as having a constant force acting on it, because this force will change direction every time the oscillator does.  It would be like having a forcing function that is a square wave with a frequency of half a full periodic movement.

Comment: You're right, I was just thinking that myself. Jeez, I should go back to trying to solve problems like this, I feel like a real dunce!

Comment: @PhilipCherian There's nothing like trying to solve a basic problem and realizing you overlooked half of it because it had been so long.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As the original question has been clarified. This answer is also no longer relevant!

I'm not sure what level your maths is at, this came up in my first year college applied maths exam.

The equation for an undamped spring oscillating is

$ mu'' + ku = 0 $

the general solutions is

$ u(t) = C_1 \cos \omega t + C_2 \sin \omega t$
where $ \omega = \sqrt{k/m}$ - is the natural frequency of the system

When there is friction, you now have a **damped system**.

$ mu″ + γu′ + ku = 0 $   is the equation you now have to solve

where γ is your damping constant (in this case your friction)
If they are real roots you get an answer of

$ u(t) = C_1e^{r_1t} + C_2e^{r_2t} $

I don't think he would have given you anything more difficult than that to solve. But if you want to explore it further here's a good link I found. https://sites.psu.edu/s17m250s4n5/files/2017/02/10.Mechanical-Vibrations-1fhhmvs.pdf

Comment: Thank you! I had heard of damped oscillations before but I was not so sure that this was the case. I have read though that damped oscillations occur when the friction is significant. Is there a value for it after the SHM motion equation is not valid anymore?

Comment: @Bee I looked up another site and the homogenous answer is still valid. If you know the initial amplitude and solve for the steady state solution you can simplify the solution and then let it equal to 0 to find t. It seems like a relatively difficult question if you haven't been exposed to this kind of maths before though.

Comment: I don't know how relevant this is.  Traditional viscous damping is proportional to the velocity.  In this case, that is not true.  The magnitude of the friction is not affected by the velocity of the block, only by it's mass.  Therefore this equation does not represent the scenario.

Comment: I think we'd need @Bee to tell us exactly what sort of friction this problem speaks of before we can be sure. I admit that it didn't cross my mind that it might just be a constant force, since that would simply shift the origin of the oscillator and it would never come to rest.

Comment: @PhilipCherian It seems it meant standard kinetic friction coefficient, not a viscous damping coefficient, so this answer and your answer don't really apply now (plus it seemed weird to ask for "time to stop" for a viscous damping, as that would always technically be infinite time.  They would have had to ask for like 1% of the initial velocity or something.

Comment: I don't think the downvotes were warranted, but I have edited my post to show that this answer is no longer relevant as the question has been updated.

Comment: @JamesBlackwell I had initially downvoted because I had assumed the question was what OP edited it to be.  Another answer seemed to have the same confusion and I realized it was unclear enough to give doubt.  I just couldn't remove the downvote until you edited it.

Comment: @JMac No worries!